# Why is keyed stream ( on a keyBy ) creating skewed downstream execution?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a case where there are 8 keys ( on a keyBy )  and the spread on slots is skewed. I have a a parallelism of 3, and the spread of keyed operations is 5,2 and 1, with 5 keys incident on a single slot. Is there a way to ensure that the distribution of keyed operation is balanced. ( We do not have partition operation on a keyed stream )

Answer (score 1):

`keyBy()` assumes a uniform distribution. In general, this problems can be solved by implementing an artificial key.

Internally, Flink calls `obj.hashCode()` on your key and distributes your record with that (and some additional logic). You can implement your own `KeySelector` that wraps your screwed key and implement a better `hashCode()` method.

Comment: "screwed" key ? There is no skew in the keys.  The output of a keyBy() are 8 different keyed streams  with 8 definitely dissimilar keys, and they become incident non uniformly on  the slots. I think we are piggy banking on the obj.hashCode() for both partitioning as well as grouping and that is the issue, which may be unavoidable. obj.hashCode()%n can be equal even if the obj ( a string in my case ) are different and n is consttant ( parallelism ? )

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't get your problem. Are you familiar with the concept of key groups in Flink? Keys are grouped according to the maximum parallelism that you defined in your program. It might solve your problem, if the maximum parallelism is set to 3 for this operator.

Comment: See also here: https://data-artisans.com/blog/apache-flink-at-mediamath-rescaling-stateful-applications